# SQL combine SELECT statements into two columns

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server-2005

TWO Tables SQL 2005 Tables

```
   Trend Table
   Enter  Exit  Number 
   .01    .01     0
   .02    .02     1
   .03    .03     2
   .04    .04     3

  Orders Table
  Ticker    Enter   Exit
   EUR        0        1
   GBP        2        3
```

Requirement: A single query to produce the Enter and Exit Values from Trend Table given only the Ticker Symbol from the Orders Table.

A Ticker Value will provide Enter and Exit Integers in the Orders Table that correspond to the Number Column in The Trend Table which points to the actual Decimal Enter and Exit values that the query should output.

Enter and Exit Values need to be in separate columns.   The following query produces output with values in 1 column only (see output)

```
 SELECT  T.Enter
 FROM Trend AS T INNER JOIN Orders AS O ON O.Enter = T.Number
 WHERE (O.Ticker = 'EUR')
 UNION
 SELECT D.Exit
 FROM Trend AS D INNER JOIN Orders AS F ON F.Exit= D.Number
 WHERE (F.Ticker = 'EUR')

 OUTPUT:
 Exit
 0.01
 0.02
```

Comment: I see someone felt there was a reason to vote down (-1) this question... I'd like to inquire why...

Comment: Didn't downvote myself, but the SHOUTING in the title and (PLEASE) are a bit annoying.

Comment: All caps in a title is grammatically correct; along with a 'please' this may imply an expectation of assistance that could be taken as rude but that was not the intent.  I will try to amend but with the notation that electronic manners can be taken too far and to me seems somewhat childish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

```
SELECT Orders.Ticker, T1.Enter, T2.Exit
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Trend T1 ON Orders.Enter = T1.Number
INNER JOIN Trend T2 ON Orders.Exit = T2.Number
```

Comment: This throws an ERROR At 'Table'  The tables are 'Trend' & 'Orders' also doesn't T1.Number on second query need to be T2.Number?

Comment: yes, but I need to add a WHERE CLAUSE TO this..   WHERE        (Orders.Ticker = 'EUR')  OTHERWISE it's good... see not so hard I guess I did not realize you could do it like that!

Comment: Just put it at the end and it should be fine